# Поиск наименьшего элемента в двусвязном списке

Tags: c++

Недавно начал изучать списки и пока не понимаю как написать функцию для поиска наименьшего элемента (в двусвязном списке). Мой список выглядит таким образом:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> class list   
{ 
   struct node       
{
   T value;     
   node *next;
   node *prev; 
};
   node *head;
   node *tail; 
public:
   list() : head(NULL), tail(NULL) {}; 
   ~list();
 void remove();
 void show_end();
 void show_beginning(); 
 void add(T value); 
};

template <typename T> list<T> :: ~list() 
{   
  while (tail) 
  {
     head = tail->prev; 
     delete [] tail; 
     tail = head; 
  }
}

template <typename T> void list<T> :: add(T value)
{
  node *temp = new node; 
  temp->next = NULL;  
  temp->value = value;

  if (head != NULL) 
 {
   temp->prev = tail; 
   tail->next = temp; 
   tail = temp; 
  }
  else 
  {
   temp->prev = NULL; 
   head = tail = temp;
  }
 }

 template <typename T> void list<T> :: remove()
 {
   if (head != NULL)
   {
    node *temp = tail;  
    tail= tail->prev;   
    tail->next = NULL;  
    delete temp;    
    }
   else
    cout << "List is empty";
  }

  template <typename T> void list<T> :: show_end()
  {
    node *temp = tail;

    while (temp != NULL)
   {
     cout << temp->value << " "; 
     temp = temp->prev; 
   }
    cout<<"\n";
  }

  template <typename T> void list<T> :: show_beginning()
  {
    node *temp = head; 
    while (temp != NULL) 
    {
      cout << temp->value << " "; 
      temp = temp->next; 
    }
    cout << "\n";
   }
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы что-то найти в структуре данных, нужно перебирать элементы этой структуры данных.

Объект, который позволяет перемещаться между элементами называется *итератор*.
Это может быть не обязательно стандартным итератором С++.

Минимальный однонаправленный итератор - это

```
template <typename T>
class list   
{ 
public:
    struct iterator {
      node* node_;

      // продвижение вперед
      void next() { node_ = node_->next; }
      // текущий элемент
      const T& value() const { return node_->value; }
      // сравнение
      bool equal(iterator other) const { return node_ == other.node_; }
    };

    // первый элемент
    iterator begin() { iterator it = {head}; return it; }
    // следующий-за-концом
    iterator end() { iterator it = {nullptr}; return it; }
};
```

Далее осталось написать алгоритм, который находит минимальный элемент:

```
template<typename Iter>
Iter min_element(Iter first, Iter last) {
  if (first.equal(last)) return last;

  auto min = first;
  first.next();

  while (!first.equal(last)) {
    if (first.value() < min.value() min = first;
    first.next();
  }

  return min;
}
```

И использование:

```
list<int> l;
...
int min = min_element(l.begin(), l.end()).value();
```

Для перемещения назад такой итератор не подходит, но в задаче говорится только про поиск минимального элемента, а для этого надо только перемещение вперед.